# vim set color for listchars tabs and spaces

Tags: vim

Using the concept of the code below in VIM
How  do I make the tabs a light grey background and a the spaces a blue background

```
" part of ~/.vimrc
" highlight tabs and trailing spaces
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:-
set list
```

Comment: Should be moved to vi.stackexchange.com so vi users can find it.

Answer (score 42):

If you use those options in your `~/.vimrc` you most certainly have read `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'` but from your question it's not really clear if you spotted the last two lines of `:help 'listchars'`:

```
The "NonText" highlighting will be used for "eol", "extends" and
"precedes".  "SpecialKey" for "nbsp", "tab" and "trail".
```

Tabs and trailing spaces use the same highlight group, though, so you won't be able to give them different background colors with those highlight groups. But you don't really need different colors, here, because you already set them to be represented by different characters.

Comment: No thanks, sir, I'll decide myself if I *really need it*. Tabs are "watch out, but a file might have tons of it without being wrong" and trailing whitespace is "THIS IS WRONG". Saying that I don't need different colors for the two very different cases is pretty presumptuous.

Comment: Still less presumptuous than believing that this answer is meant for you… and thus failing to read it correctly and *in context*.

Comment: As far as I can tell, questions and answers on this platform are meant for anyone and everyone with the same problem. And even if you're right and this isn't for me for some reason, that in no way addresses my criticism, as it's just as presumptuous to claim that the asker doesn't need different colors. And I don't think I missed any context, let alone context that makes a case for such a patronizing remark at the end of an otherwise decent answer (if not one that actively tries to be helpful). Please enlighten me about that context that made that warranted...

Answer (score 10):

this is one way:

first create two hi-groups:

```
:hi GroupA ctermbg=blue ctermfg=.. guibg=...
:hi GroupB ctermbg=gray ctermfg=.. guibg=..
```

then

```
:match GroupA / \+$/
:2match GroupB /\t/
```

Comment: This works great. To make all whitespace dark gray:

`:hi Whitespace ctermfg=DarkGray` and
`:match Whitespace /\s/`

Comment: That matches all whitespace, `:match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/` works better here.

Comment: ":match ExtraWhitespace" was not found on my system (Arch Linux; Vim 8.0), but this worked:  ":hi Whitespace ctermfg=LightGray" plus "match Whitespace /\s\+$/"

Answer (score 8):

You can't, at least not in an easy way that is 100% correct.

As @romainl has said, Vim only offers **one highlight group for all listchar types** representing characters, viz. `SpecialKey`.

The workaround implementation of @Kent has several shortcomings:

- It only works for the first / current window; you'd need `:autocmd`s to define it for new windows, too.
- It does not consider whether `'list'` is actually set; hooking into its changes isn't directly possible.
- It clobbers the `:match` slots; this could be prevented via `matchadd()`, but its use is more complex.

So, think hard whether that feature is really worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you think it's possible to rather have color background instead of text using list. If I a understanding you correctly I can pick either?

Comment: To just highlight (with the same color) the background, just `:set listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:\ ` and choose a background color via `:hi Specialkey guibg=...`

Comment: You could improve this answer by showing how to address each of these issues. It's not that complicated and it makes the answer infinitely more useful than just a list of criticisms on another answer...

Comment: @Jasper I certainly would have added that; you seem to have missed that I mentioned _isn't possible_ / _is complex_, and my conclusion is that wanting different highlighting is not worth it (in a Vimscript implementation; an extension directly in Vim's source code would be something else).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this in my vimrc for a long time, probably from elsewhere on StackOverflow; it highlights extraneous whitespace as red:

```
 highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
 match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t\|[^\t]\zs\t\+/
```

To turn this into what the question specifically asks for, highlighting whitespace at the end gray:

```
 highlight SpecialKey ctermbg=blue guibg=blue
 highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=lightgray guibg=lightgray
 match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```